# Why does stripe have a client_secret in payment_Intent ? What is the use case?

Tags: security, stripe-payments, logic, payment-gateway, payment

client_secret - https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-client_secret

client_secret is {payment_intent_id}+"_secret_"+{hash} .

I understand that the client_secret is used to do payment from the client side and since it has the payment_intent_id in it the stripe server can understand which payment_intent object it has to refer to and how much amount it has to debit.

But what is the exact use case of the hash that is additionally added in client_secret ?

Edit: I'm trying to understand what stripe does on its end using the hash.

Comment: It's just a detail, the format of the string is specific to Stripe and you shouldn't attempt to parse it or do anything with it beyond simply pass the complete `client_secret` string as returned from the backend API to documented places in the Stripe frontend libraries that ask for it.

Comment: @karllekko, I understand what you said. But what I am trying to actually understand is what does stripe do on it's end with the hash. Is it some security measure. If yes , then what could it be ?

Comment: Why do you want to know? Nobody except Stripe is going to know why it's built the way it is so you'd need to attempt to ask them. I'd imagine the basic idea is because the PaymentIntent ID is fairly public information, but the complete client_secret should be guarded a little more since it can be used to attempt a payment, so it adds a layer of security since you need something more than just the public ID to attempt a payment.